# Workflow automation for populating QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

Is there a tool in QGIS which populates fields within the attribute table?

I know I can edit it manually but what I want is to include that tool in the workflow automation process.

I want to label the output rather than put it on the key of the map. To label I need to have a field where I can add the label. Since this is part of a larger process in the Graphical Modeler I need to automate it rather than adding the field and name manually.

What I'm interested in is if there is a tool or Expression in the Field Calculator that can return the name of the input layer and add it to the attribute table of the new/ output layer of the Field Calculator tool

Comment: Populate them with what? At which point of your workflow? What is your workflow? What have you tried? How do you populate the fields currently?

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for the Field calculator...

Comment: Do you want to add a "calculate field" step to a processing model ? You need to give a lot more detail on your workflow to get answer

Comment: My model adds a field but at the moment it's just an empty field. I want to add a certain string so I can label the feature.

Comment: Is the any logic behind the label? We need more details still.

Comment: Yes, there is a logic. I want to label the output rather than putting in on the key of the map. In order to label I need to have a field where I can add the label. Since this is part of a larger process in the Graphical Modeller I need to automate it rather than adding the field and name manually. What I'm interested in is if there is a tool or Expression in the Field Calculator that can return the name of the input layer and add it to the attribute table of the new/ output layer of the Field Calculator tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There are several options I may refer you to:

1. ["Field calculator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#field-calculator) : `qgis:fieldcalculator`

   > Opens the field calculator. You can use all the
   > supported expressions and functions.
   >
   > A new layer is created with the result of the expression.
   >
   > The field calculator is very useful when used in The graphical
   > modeler.
2. ["Refactor fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) : `qgis:refactorfields`

   > Allows editing the structure of the attribute table of a vector layer.
   >
   > Fields can be modified in their type and name, using a fields mapping.
   >
   > The original layer is not modified. A new layer is generated, which
   > contains a modified attribute table, according to the provided fields
   > mapping.
   >
   > Refactor layer fields allows to:
   >
   > - Change field names and types
   > - Add and remove fields
   > - Reorder fields
   > - Calculate new fields based on expressions
   > - Load field list from another layer
3. [Advanced Python field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#advanced-python-field-calculator) : `qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator`

   > Adds a new attribute to a vector layer, with values resulting from
   > applying an expression to each feature.
   >
   > The expression is defined as a Python function.
4. [Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#execute-sql) : `qgis:executesql`

   > Runs a simple or complex query with SQL syntax on the source layer.
   >
   > Beside a simple query, you can add expressions or variables within the
   > SQL query parameter itself. This is particulary useful if this
   > algorithm is executed within a Processing model and you want to use a
   > model input as a parameter of the query. An example of a query will
   > then be `SELECT * FROM [% @table %]` where `@table` is the variable
   > that identifies the model input.
   >
   > The result of the query will be added as a new layer.

---

Answering the question "Expression in the Field Calculator that returns the name of the input layer?"

As was mentioned by @AlexandreNeto:

> you can get the layer name using the variable `/@layer_name`, there is
> also the `/@layer_id`.

Check these article for more details:

- [EXPLORING VARIABLES IN QGIS 2.12, PART 1](https://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-2-12-part-1/)
- [EXPLORING VARIABLES IN QGIS PT 2: PROJECT MANAGEMENT](https://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-2-project-management/)
- [EXPLORING VARIABLES IN QGIS PT 3: LAYER LEVEL VARIABLES](https://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-3-layer-level-variables/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very helpful! Is there an expression in the Field Calculator that returns the name of the input file?

Comment: sorry for asking, do you mean *file* or *layer*?

Comment: sorry the input layer name. Thank you

Comment: @CuriousGirl you can get the layer name using the variable /@layer_name, there is also the /@layer_id